# Nodejs register hooks import

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a hook to use ESM modules without .js extension. I am trying to use register() from node:modules, the idea is intercept the import and before search file put .js extension in run time. The example is:

```
// index.js
import { glob } from "glob";
import express from "express";
import { test } from "./second";
express()
console.log(test)
console.log(glob(''))
```

the hooks is:

```
//hook.js
export async function resolve(specifier, context, nextResolve) {
    console.log({
        specifier,
        context,
        nextResolve
    })
    if (typeof specifier === 'string' && specifier.startsWith('file://') && !specifier.endsWith('.js'))
        specifier += '.js'
    return nextResolve(specifier, context)

  // Take an `import` or `require` specifier and resolve it to a URL.
}

let a = 1
export const load = (url, context, loadDefaultAsync) => {
    if (typeof url === 'string' && url.startsWith('file://') && !url.endsWith('.js'))
        url += '.js'
  console.log(`loading ${url}`);
    console.log(context)
    console.log(a++)
  return loadDefaultAsync(url, context, loadDefaultAsync);
};
```

The file that I am trying to import:

```
//second.js
export const test = 'test'
```

And last, the register:

```
//loader.js
import { register } from 'node:module';

register('./hook.js', import.meta.url);
```

This is the script that I use to load the index:

```
node --loader ./src/hook.js src/index
```

When I run the file I have this error:

```
(node:17584) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; 

instead use `register()`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("./src/hook.js", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
{
  specifier: 'file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/index.js',
  context: {
    conditions: [ 'node', 'import', 'node-addons' ],
    importAssertions: {},
    parentURL: undefined
  },
  nextResolve: [AsyncFunction: nextResolve]
}
loading file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/index.js
{ format: 'module', importAssertions: {} }
1
{
  specifier: 'glob',
  context: {
    conditions: [ 'node', 'import', 'node-addons' ],
    importAssertions: {},
    parentURL: 'file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/index.js'
  },
  nextResolve: [AsyncFunction: nextResolve]
}
{
  specifier: 'express',
  context: {
    conditions: [ 'node', 'import', 'node-addons' ],
    importAssertions: {},
    parentURL: 'file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/index.js'
  },
  nextResolve: [AsyncFunction: nextResolve]
}

node:internal/process/esm_loader:40
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\Daniel-Pc\Dev-Pro\nodejs\js-stuff\src\second' imported from E:\Daniel-Pc\Dev-Pro\nodejs\js-stuff\src\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:833:28)
    at resolve (file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/hook.js:9:12)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:833:28)
    at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:278:30)
    at handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:168:24)
    at Immediate.checkForMessages (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:117:28) {
  url: 'file:///E:/Daniel-Pc/Dev-Pro/nodejs/js-stuff/src/second',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

The idea is create a hook to add .js before import. Is that possible?